# Convert curl POST to urllib request python3

Tags: python-3.x, curl, post, urllib

The following curl command works as intended. Uses POST to send a bit of information to a web site.

```sh
    curl 'https://...' \
     -X PUT \
     -d "submission[posted_grade]=65" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer 10~X"
```

What should be the equivalent python3 code, gives an Error 500: Internal Server Error

```py
url_string = 'https://...'
data = "submission[posted_grade]=40"
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url_string, data)
req.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer 10~X")
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

Already tried

```py
data = {'submission[posted_grade]': '40'}
data = json.dumps(data)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

Which gives "HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity"

Any ideas on fixing it?

Comment: Your `curl` request is a `PUT`, the python one is a `POST`. Also you're setting the `Content-Type` to `applicaton/json` in one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cody

Lesson learned, PUT != POST

The following code works as expected:

```
url_string = 'https://...'
data = "submission[posted_grade]=40"
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url_string, data=data, method='PUT')
req.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer 10~X")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```